# How to get original memo text from TfrxReport.OnClickObject

Tags: delphi, onclick, fastreport

I have a FR4 report which I want to make interactive. Report is built upon data from a dataset. In the designer I put expressions like **[Q."NAME"]** into memo objects and they become a values from the dataset at the time of report being built.

I know that there is a **TfrxReport.OnClickObject** event. But from within this event handler I can only obtain a memo text.

So, my question is how to get an original expression (**[Q."NAME"]** in my exmaple) from **TfrxReport.OnClickObject** event handler.